# how to have a complete background on site fit to screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

I hope I ask this correctly. What I want to do is set a background to the body of my website page which fills the users screen. So the image stretches if the screen is big and when they reduce the browser the background image reduces with it?

```
#homebdy
{
   background-image:url('../images/bghome.jpg');
}
```

Comment: http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ ( The page itself is a demo, but unless you have big resolution you might want to dl it and test the examples in the package. )

Comment: I think you will never fill exactly the viewport size, because you can't stretch photos to a different ratio, f.e.: viewport ratio on widescreen is 16:9 and viewport size on most common monitors at home is 4:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
#homebdy{
  background-image:url('../images/bghome.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Next step would be to center the image depending on viewport size. There for I would recommend the use of jQuery. For example if you use pictures with a ratio of 4:3, then do this:

```
var indent = (($(window).width() - (($(this).height())/3)*4) / 2);
$('#homebdy').offset({left: indent});
```

You can see a live example on [a website I am building currently](http://www.nicray.com)

Comment: This is the only true cross-browser method. `background-size` only works in IE9+.

Comment: when i set the image the page scrolls down, it shouldnt scroll down it should just fill the page

Comment: also i like the way your gallery is on the home page, where do i go to get a demo of how to build that

Comment: Try to give the parent div position: relative

Answer (score 2):

If you want your image to be streched according to its container:

```
#homebdy {
  background-image:url('../images/bghome.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the following CSS:

```
#homebdy{
  background-image:url('../images/bghome.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this would stretch the image, it would just repeat the image if the resolution was too high for the image dimensions.

Comment: Well what would I do if my jpg was a 5px * 5px image and I wanted it tiled? By default CSS repeats background images.

Comment: Have YOU tried it, because it behaves exactly like Curt suggests.

Comment: yes, i have tried it. and its working and this is not for a small image. I have suggested the answer according to the question.

Comment: Gaurav, the OP is looking for a solution where the image stretches. The image doesn't stretch in your code. The point is to use image of any size, big or small, so that it would always fill the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try these options. If you want to stretch the image then background-size: 100%;, background-size: cover; will work. If you wanna keep it proportional then use background-size: contain

http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/background-size/

Comment: you could also use max-width: 100% or max-height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

> try this
>
> ## homebdy{   background:url(../images/bghome.jpg);   height: 100%;   position: absolute;   top: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
background-image:url('your urlurl');
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* this line not necessary */
```

Solution of this problem with CSS3

Though this post is old, As with 2014 best soln.